# Second parameter never arrives

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing, jquery-events

I have created a custom trigger with jQuery that accepts two parameters, but the second never arrives.

```
//firstly
$(Crafty).bind('onTsxLoaded', function (event, tsx, firstSpriteId) {
    console.log("tsx", tsx);
    console.log("firstspriteid", firstSpriteId);
}

//<snip>
success: function (xml) {
   var firstSpriteId = tileset.attr("firstgid");
   console.log("done loading ts", firstSpriteId);
   $(Crafty).trigger('onTsxLoaded', xml, firstSpriteId);
}
```

yields:

```
"done loading ts" 1
"tsx" object
"firstspriteid" undefined
```

Why is firstspriteid 1 before trigger and undefined right after?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass extra parameters to an event using `trigger`, they need to be in an array.

```
$(Crafty).trigger('onTsxLoaded', [xml, firstSpriteId]);
```

Comment: Aha! Ofcourse. I had seen it in the docs, but had interpreted it as "optional". Thx!

Comment: @BorisCallens: Yeah, usually the `[]` means "optional" argument.  Took me a while to figure that out too.  I think one of the examples on the docs page shows that it needs to be an array.